# MongoDB - update multiple documents solution - update document counter or insert if doesn't exist

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following `titles` collection structure:

```
[
   ...,
   { 
      "_id" : ...,
      "title": "some title",
      "counter": 3
   }, 
   { 
      "_id" : ...,
      "title": "some title 2",
      "counter": 1
   }, 
   ...
]
```

Given a list of titles (e.g. "title1", "title2", etc.), I want to insert the title with counter 1 if it doesn't exist, or increment the counter by 1 if it already exist.

Can I do it in 1 mongo query for many titles?

I know I can run an update query for every title but it seems inefficient.

Thanks!

(P.S - I saw a lot of posts about "increment or insert of doesn't exist" but didn't find a solution for many)

Comment: check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you've multiple filters then you would normally use `$in` operator, So if you do like :

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').updateMany(
        {title: {$in : ["some title",  "some title 3"]}},
         {$inc : {counter: 1}}, {upsert : true})
```

Above, query would only update matching documents but doesn't do upsert. Since you've multiple filters then you can take advantage of [.bulkwrite()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/index.html#db-collection-bulkwrite) which can have a group of operations up to 100k.

```
let bulkArr = [];

let titles = ["some title", "some title3"];

for (const title of titles) {
  bulkArr.push({
    updateOne: {
      filter:  { ...{title} },
      update: { $inc: { counter: 1 } },
      upsert : true
    },
  });
}

db.collection.bulkWrite(bulkArr);
```

This `.bulkWrite()` would also perform multiple update operations on database but by using this you can avoid doing multiple DB calls.

Comment: nice. it is best practice to use bulks on the server? because in the documentation it is under "mongo shell".

Comment: @user3343396 : yes it’s ok to use rather than doing multiple db calls to achieve the same if at all you wanted to reduce the data in bulkwrite you can chunk your data and call bulkwrite multiple times in call